# Firebase automatically logging out users after an hour

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, next.js

So, I did some research about this and I understand that firebase updates a refresh token after every hour as firebase id tokens expire after an hour. I read that firebase refreshing token after an hour is an automatic thing and user doesn't have to do anything about it.

But my user is getting logged out after an hour automatically. I want the user session to persist as long as the user doesn't logs out willingly.I don't know how to debug this either.

Here's my package.json -

```
{
    "name": "with-firebase-authentication",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "export": "next export"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^8.2.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
        "js-cookie": "2.2.1",
        "luxon": "^1.25.0",
        "next": "latest",
        "nookies": "^2.5.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
        "swr": "0.2.3",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    },
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

I used this example as the base of my application -
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication

Edit - Here's some additional code;

userCookies.js

```
import cookies from 'js-cookie';

export const getUserFromCookie = () => {
    const cookie = cookies.get('auth');
    if (!cookie) {
        return;
    }
    return JSON.parse(cookie);
};

export const setUserCookie = user => {
    cookies.set('auth', user, {
        // firebase id tokens expire in one hour
        // set cookie expiry to match
        // expires: 1 / 24,
        expires: 1 / 24,
    });
};

export const removeUserCookie = () => cookies.remove('auth');
```

useUser.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import initFirebase from '../auth/initFirebase';
import { removeUserCookie, setUserCookie, getUserFromCookie } from './userCookies';
import { mapUserData } from './mapUserData';

initFirebase();

const useUser = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Firebase updates the id token every hour, this
        // makes sure the react state and the cookie are
        // both kept up to date
        const cancelAuthListener = firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async user => {
            if (user) {
                const userData = await mapUserData(user);
                setUserCookie(userData);
                setUser(userData);
            } else {
                removeUserCookie();
                setUser();
            }
        });

        const userFromCookie = getUserFromCookie();
        if (!userFromCookie) {
            router.push('/');
            return;
        }
        setUser(userFromCookie);

        return () => {
            cancelAuthListener();
        };
    }, []);

    return { user, logout };
};

export { useUser };
```

mapUserData.js

```
export const mapUserData = (user) => {
  let token
  const { uid, email } = user
  user.getIdToken(true).then(id => token = id)
  return {
    id: uid,
    email,
    token,
  }
}
```

I think there's some problem with the cookies and not firebase authentication.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should add all relevant code into the question itself - do not link out to external resources, as they might become stale in the future and render this question useless to others.  It should be clear from the code you add here what the problem is and how you're observing it.

Comment: Yeah I undestand your point but I don't know exactly what is causing the problem. If I have to add relevant code then I'll have to add a lot of code. I don't even know if that's allowed over here. But I will add some more code as you said to make my question clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION or NONE.

Read more in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence